# Doctrine undefined function apc_fetch

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2011/05/setting-up-codeigniter-2-with-doctrine-2-the-right-way/), which gives a detail explanation about how to set up CodeIgniter and Doctrine. I'm using CodeIgniter 2.1.0 and Doctrine 2.2.1, but I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function `Doctrine\Common\Cache\apc_fetch()` in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/emma_watson_shrine/application/libraries/Doctrine/Common/Cache/ApcCache.php on line 52

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 12):

You need to enable the APC extension for PHP.

Follow [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.installation.php) guide.

Alternatively, you could use a different caching driver, like memcache, and change the Doctrine config in accordance to that.

Check the [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/caching.html) for alternate caching drivers. Perhaps the simplest solution would be to use **ArrayCache** in development.

Answer (score 5):

Since php 5.5 apc is no longer used. You should install apcu.

E.g.

`apt install php5.6-apcu`

More info here:

http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php

And for those on php 7 there's a backwards compatibility module:

```
apt-get install php7.0-apcu
apt-get install php7.0-apcu-bc
```

Also, you might need to add this repository:

```
apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get update
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't install APC and just want to run it then in doctrine-cli.php at line 6, change mode:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
```

to

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

Open Doctrine.php file, at line 36 ~ 43, you will see why!

Answer (score 1):

you need to install apc extension to work with caching. So just download the extension and install it.

This one will help you to install APC extension on apache.

http://kvcodes.com/2014/06/solution-call-undefined-function-apc_fetch/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting this on a Mac, just install `apcu` using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

`brew install php56-apcu`

(and enable the extension, if required).

Comment: Error: No available formula with the name "php56-apcu"

Answer (score 0):

On OSX I had to run:

```
pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
pecl install apcu-4.0.11
```

to install for PHP 5.6

https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-mojave-apache-mysql-vhost-apc