# Can't load the webpage in symfony production

Tags: php, symfony, apc

When I run the `app_dev.php` file, the webpage works fine. But it shows blank page when I run the `app.php`. I tried to run this command `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`. But it produces error like this

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\Cache\apc_fetch() in /home/david/Documents/web_mikro/mikroweb/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/ApcCache.php on line 40
```

I don't have any idea about this. Also I try to create one file to clear apc in web/ folder. This is the temporary file

```
<?php
apc_clear_cache();
apc_clear_cache('user');
apc_clear_cache('opcode');
```

And I delete this file. But nothing works. It keeps show the blank page in `app.php`. Also I have updated this

```
sudo apt-get install php-apc
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and this

```
apt-get install apache2
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
apt-get install php-pear
apt-get install php5-dev
apt-get install make
apt-get install apache2-prefork-dev
pecl install apc
```

But the result is same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142938/doctrine-undefined-function-apc-fetch ?

Comment: duplicate? I think it's not duplicate. My problem is in symfony while the other is codeigniter

Comment: I don't see the difference since the pb is located in doctrine / apc.

Comment: But http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142938/doctrine-undefined-function-apc-fetch doesn't solve my problem. I have tried these.

Comment: Enabling the APC extension did not solve your issue? apc_fetch() is called in doFetch() of \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache

Comment: I will update my question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41024/discussion-between-david-and-brice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to add at the beginning of your app.php file:

```
phpinfo();exit;
```

And then look that apc is correctly enabled

Also look at your PHP errors (/var/log/...)

And eventually check that your config_prod configuration has apc enabled, something like:

```
framework:
    validation:
        cache: apc

doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: apc
        result_cache_driver: apc
        query_cache_driver: apc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Ubuntu, would be better to install APC form distribution binaries instead of PECL

```
sudo apt-get install php-apc
```

Also make sure you restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```